# How to judge if the next line needs to be indented?

Tags: regex, algorithm, line

I am writing a function to achieve an auto indent for an editor in the next line.

In the case

```
1  void test(){//test}
```

by press Enter, I can get the next line. My question is how to indent the **//test** with 1 tab in the next line?

```
1  void test(){
2     //test
3  }
```

**The current code indent the 2nd line by searching if there are brackets like '{' '[' '(' .**

But if code like this, the 2nd line will not indent

```
1  if(true)
2  //test
```

So how to solve it when there is no bracket?

And I can get the string and any position of the 1st line .

Comment: you can check for `if else` manually, along with `for while and do-while`, functions will always have braces

Comment: Thank for your answer, checking for `if else`, `while` and so on is too complicated. I have this question here because the client sometimes will not add brackets.@gc7

Comment: Use regex probably- `/^((if|else|while|for)(\(.*?\)))$/`

Comment: @vivek_23 Regex is a good way and I will try it. :)